# Can i add Salesforce developer org or Sandbox Org into Social studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sandbox, servicecloud, social-studio

I want to add either Salesforce developer org or Sandbox Org into Social studio . Then want to use it in Engagement macros so that i can test Lead and case creation In Service cloud from social studio Engage Tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can:

> Configure Social Studio Automate to connect to one or more Salesforce
> orgs. Once connected, you can enable automated rules to send posts
> directly to those orgs and open them as new cases.
>
> You can connect Social Studio Automate to **one or more production or
> sandbox Salesforce Orgs**.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_sh_salesforcecom.htm&type=5